# Summing data by window size in grouped data

Tags: matlab, accumarray

I am quite new to matlab and I am trying to find a way to accomplish the following task without using for loops:

I have a data set looking like this:

```
data = [1 5; 1 3; 1 8; 2 1; 2 2; 2 5; 3 3; 3 8; 3 4]
```

the first column is a group (being a month year combination in the future)

Now I want to calculate a sum over the second column with a given window size but only if the group index is the same - if not the maximal sum in this group shall be calculated.

With window size=2 I would like to create the following result:

```
summed_data = [1 8; 1 11; 1 8; 2 3; 2 7; 2 5; 3 11; 3 12; 3 4]
```

With a window size of 3 the result would look like this:

```
summed_data = [1 16; 1 11; 1 8; 2 8; 2 7; 2 5; 3 15; 3 12; 3 4]
```

and so on.

I thought about using accumarray by creating sufficient subindexes - but I have a problem with the window size and that the sums are overlapping.

Has anyone an idea on how to implement it without using loops?

Thanks in advance and best regards
stephan

Comment: In the first column, you have three each for `1s`, `2s`, `3s`. Is it always like that? i.e. number of those labels are always the same for all labels?

Comment: Hello Divakar, no, this was just the (bad example) case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ws = 2; k = [ones(ws,1);zeros(mod(ws,2),1)];
C = accumarray(data(:,1),data(:,2),[],@(v){conv(v,k,'same')})
```

You seem to be anchoring to the current pixel in the window and looking forward.  Is that correct?

Not sure if this covers all corner cases, but it might steer you in the right direction.

**Test: ws = 2**

```
ws = 2; k = [ones(ws,1);zeros(mod(ws,2),1)];
C = accumarray(data(:,1),data(:,2),[],@(v){conv(v,k,'same')});
summed_data = [data(:,1) vertcat(C{:})]
summed_data =

     1     8
     1    11
     1     8
     2     3
     2     7
     2     5
     3    11
     3    12
     3     4
```

**Test: ws = 3**

```
summed_data = [data(:,1) vertcat(C{:})]
summed_data =

     1    16
     1    11
     1     8
     2     8
     2     7
     2     5
     3    15
     3    12
     3     4
```

Comment: Not sure how efficient this would be, but seems to work indeed! At least a clean solution.

Comment: @Divakar It might break down for higher window sizes, but I don't fully understand the intent and how to anchor the windows sum the way the OP wants it.

Comment: @Divakar Yeah, I'm not sure what the right results should be.  The function called by `accumarray` might need to be tuned and the kernel padded, depending on the desired behavior.

Comment: This would be my first approach too +1

Comment: works like a charme - thanks for the handy solution and the presentation of the power of accumarray!